# Creating tensors with null as batch dimension in tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

My model expects an input of `[null,12]` as suggested by the error. When i create a tensor

```
tf.tensor([12 values], [null, 12])
```

It throws this `Error: Tensor must have a shape comprised of positive integers but got shape [,13]`. How do i fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

The model expects a tensor of shape `[null, 12]`, `null` is there to indicate that there is a batch dimension which is a positive integer.
A tensor itself cannot be created with one of its dimension value to be null.

The error can be fix by

```
tf.tensor([12 values], [1, 12])
```

There is 12 values - which can be seen as one batch of 12 elements. Consequently, The shape is `[1, 12]`.

If the batch size is not known, the tensor can be created that way:

```
tf.tensor([12 values]).reshape([-1, 12])
```

In the latter case, the shape is saying: "I don't know how many elements there are, but it is a multiple of 12 - figure out the batch size by yourself". But if the values happens not to be a multiple of 12, it will throw an error when creating the tensor.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I fixed it by training the network again by specifying the shape properly during creating of Sequential class.